# How to create id in element in template when I have passed parameter?

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates

How to create id in element in template when I have passed parameter ?
I have tried something like

```
<button id="p_"+{{key}} >TEST</button>
```

but in rendered HTML id is just **p_** . Can someone tell me how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<button id="p_{{key}}">TEST</button>`

you need the key to be Inside the quotes

I'm assuming you were using `+` to concat strings.  I don't believe html supports any operations like that.

Answer (score 1):

```
<button id="p_{{key}}">TEST</button>
```